# www.bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint not verified issue while pushing changes

Tags: ssl, mercurial, ssl-certificate, dvcs, bitbucket

I am trying to push changes to a project I am contributing to. I have permissions to commit to the project and has a valid account in bitbucket. I am getting the below error while pushing the changes. Appreciate help on fixing this.

[image]

Comment: Note it seems they blog about this, at least they did today: http://blog.bitbucket.org/2014/03/06/ssl-certificates-are-changing/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It started working after adding the below to repo specific hgrc file

```
[hostfingerprints]
bitbucket.org = 24:9c:45:8b:9c:aa:ba:55:4e:01:6d:58:ff:e4:28:7d:2a:14:ae:3b
```

based on the suggestion [here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/2780/getting-warning-while-using-https-and-ssh)

[certificate was changed on jan 19, 2012](http://twitter.com/#!/bitbucket/status/160066801319948288)

[Bitbucket’s SSL certificates are changing on March 6, 2014](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2014/03/06/ssl-certificates-are-changing/)

Answer (score 2):

I did as FalconSer mentions above, with the exception that I placed it in /etc/mercuial/hgrc so it'd be correct for all local mercurial repo's.